# how to add dynamic link tag prefetch with hash files on angular8 SSR

Tags: angular, typescript, express, server-side

I'm using angular 8 as SSR or angular universal, we found very difficult adding dynamic prefetch link tag with the main angular files.

After building as ssr, the code inject at the end of the index.html a line like this,

```
<script src="runtime.58b180e8c30580ec9ea9.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.ea80a4cb53fa86a5c510.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills.c8c0431bcdc0afdb2644.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.2bbb0f7e81eb835e1cea.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.e7551457890efc085d4b.js" defer></script><script src="main.80bdfc18f9240a3efe5c.js" defer></script></body>

</html>
```

However, on the head tag we need to have something like this

```
  <link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/runtime.js">
  <link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/polyfills-es5.js">
  <link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/polyfills.js">
  <link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/scripts.js">
  <link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/vendor.js">
```

The problem is that every build will have a different hash so we need an option to detect the hashing on the server before rendering the page.

Any ideas, how we can do this?

Angular 8 as SSR, with express.js